# How to download zip file and parse csv file from it in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a script which hit an URL and downloads a zip file, unzip it. Now I am facing problem while parsing CSV file which I get after unzip.

```
import csv
from requests import get
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

request = get('https://example.com/some_file.zip')
zip_file = ZipFile(BytesIO(request.content))
files = zip_file.namelist()
with open(files[0], 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: what is the error/problem?

Answer (score 5):

When you do `files = zip_file.namelist()`, you just list the names of the files in the zip archive; these files are not yet extracted from the zip and you cannot `open` them as *local* files, like you're doing.

You can directly read a stream of data from a zip file using [`ZipFile.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open).

So this should work:

```
zip_file = ZipFile(BytesIO(request.content))
files = zip_file.namelist()
with zip_file.open(files[0], 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    ...
```

Comment: you are right that was the issue but now its throwing this issue `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`

Comment: can you help me with the above error so I can accept the answer

Comment: You can coerce the bytes to a string, but you may need to specify the encoding. Something like this might work: `csvreader = csv.reader(str(csvfile, "utf-8-sig"))`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't imported the `csv` module.  Try putting `import csv` at the top with your imports.

Comment: I forgot to mention here, but that's not the issue here but the problem is it is not printing anything but file is not empty

Answer (score 0):

```
response = requests.get(url)
with io.BytesIO(response.content) as zip_file:
    with zipfile.ZipFile() as zip_file:
        # Get first file in the archive
        for zip_info in zip_file.infolist():
            logger.debug(zip_info)
            # Open file
            with zip_file.open(zip_info) as file:
                # Load CSV file, decode binary to text
                with io.TextIOWrapper(file) as text:
                    return csv.DictReader(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

So. After some hours of searching and trying, I finally got something working. Here is my script.

So my need was:

- Download a ZIP file.
- Find in that zip file a specific text file with
  "anystring" in the name
- Extract from that text file the 1st URL containing the string "csv"

```
#!/bin/env python
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
import requests
import re
import sys

# define url value
url = "https://whateverurlyouneed"

# Define string to be found in the file name to be extracted
filestr = "anystring"

# Define string to be found in URL
urlstr = "anystring"

# Define regex to extract URL
regularex = r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|(([^\s()<>]+|(([^\s()<>]+)))))+(?:(([^\s()<>]+|(([^\s()<>]+))))|[^\s`!()[]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))"

# download zip file
content = requests.get(url)

# Open stream
zipfile = ZipFile(BytesIO(content.content))

# Open first file from the ZIP archive containing 
# the filestr string in the name
data = [zipfile.open(file_name) for file_name in zipfile.namelist() if filestr in file_name][0]

# read lines from the file. If csv found, print URL and exit
# This will return the 1st URL containing CSV in the opened file
for line in data.readlines():
    if urlstr in line.decode("latin-1"):
        urls = re.findall(regularex,line.decode("latin-1"))
        print([url[0] for url in urls])
        break
sys.exit(0)
```